# Flash colour when value in ListView cell changes

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a ListView (shown below). I would like the cells to flash a colour when the value displayed changes (ideally one colour for increases, one for decreases).

I know how to write the animation for the colour (below), and I'm pretty sure I need to use a cell template so I can hook a trigger up to the style to start the animation. I'm just unsure what the best place to hook the trigger up to.

I was hoping that I could hook into the PropertyChanged events, but I'm not sure how.

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyListItems}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>                
                <GridViewColumn Header="Value1" Width="50" CellTemplate="{StaticResource Value1CellTemplate}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Value2" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value2}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Cell Template and Colour Animation:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Value1CellTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LowerBound}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <Storyboard x:Key="IncreaseValueColourAnimation" Duration="0:0:2">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="Red" KeyTime="0:0:0.1" />
                <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="Transparent" KeyTime="0:0:2" />
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `TargetUpdated` event off FrameworkElement.

> Occurs when the target value changes
>   for any property binding on this
>   element.

You should then be able to use an EventTrigger to run your animation.

Comment: I'm sure Ben Von Handorf would appreciate you flagging this as the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I can come up with in the limited time I had available. I can help you further tomorrow if necessary. Mind, I cheated by using a TextBox for the CellTemplate, that enabled me to use the TextChanged event to trigger the ColorAnimation. I could not get your KeyframeAnimation to work, so I used a ColorAnimation. Good luck!

```
<Window x:Class="CellFlashSpike.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="IncreaseValueColourAnimation"
                    Duration="0:0:2"
                    AutoReverse="True">
            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBox.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                            To="Red"/>
        </Storyboard>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="FlashTemplate">
            <TextBox Width="50" Text="{Binding Path=.}">
                <TextBox.Style>
                    <Style>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBox.TextChanged">
                                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <StaticResource ResourceKey="IncreaseValueColourAnimation"/>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger.Actions>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Style>
            </TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Numbers}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource FlashTemplate}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>

namespace CellFlashSpike
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public List<string> Numbers { get; set; }

        public Window1()
        {
            Numbers = new List<string> { "3", "4" };
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry was a badly written animation, fixed in question now.

Comment: You're right, TextBox is cheating. Got it with the Binding.TargetUpdated property suggested above.